# Umbraco suddenly login failed for user

Tags: sql, session, authentication, umbraco, system.web

I'm currently using the CMS Umbraco for my website to handle my blog. While suddenly the login won't work for any user.

UmbracoTracelog

> Event Id: 0, state: Login attempt failed for username test from IP
>   address 127.0.0.1

- I've checked my MSSQL where all instances are running and connecting
  correctly to my project.
- I've tried the UmbracoAdminReset.dll but it doesn't make any
  difference.
- I've tried to manually change the password in the MSSQL Umbraco users
  table with the same login attempt failed error
- I've tried to login on different user and still gets the same error
- I've built i have restarted the computer but the error still applies, this worked earlier today, All i have done is just working with Disqus comment API on their website.

I've noticed in my Web.config that i have errors in **(I manually replaced the PublicKeyToken here with *******)**

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***************" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

> Invalid module qualification: Failed to resolve assembly System.Web.Providers
>
> Cannot Resolve symbol  DefaultSessionStateProivder

The website runs fine, I get to the login page, I just cannot login because I get Login attempt failed error.

**EDIT:**

In my Errorlist i can see 28 messages that says:

> Could not find schema information for element __

- UmbracoConfiguration
- security
- settings
  and 25 more with the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the DLL for '**System.Web.Providers**' OR you are using a different version.

If you publish from Visual Studio, ensure you have set '**CopyLocal**' to TRUE if your project references this DLL.

You could also just try to FTP the missing file up to your hosting account.

Let me know how it goes.

Regards

Craig

Comment: Thanks for answering Craig, I'm not able to publish this website since i'm running it locally on IIS and i just updated my thread with more information what i could find.

I'm a rookie when it comes to FTP.

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using? Have you tried downloading Umbraco and comparing the web.config with your local one? Seems like you might not have copied something across correctly.

Comment: I am using v.7.6.1. Noticed there's an update avaliable but that could not occur this could it? I'm going to take your tip and compare the files and come back if i find anything odd!

Comment: I am currently using v7.6.1 and I haven't run into any issues so far (fingers crossed). Let me know how it goes.